# how to add space between HintText and Drawableleft in EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I tried adding "DrawablePadding" to it but, it is not working.

```
<EditText
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:hint="Email"/>
```

Comment: try only `paddingLeft`. I don't know what `drawablePadding` does :/

Comment: tried android:paddingLeft?

Comment: android:drawablePadding="10dp" work on your edittext code

Comment: Removing irrelevant tags and a single space.

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:ems="10"` and add `android:drawablePadding="5dip"`

Answer (score 0):

```
              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
                android:drawablePadding="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#939598"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```